# Longest recurring cycle in its decimal fraction - a bug or a misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, math, logic

This is fairly 'math-y' but I'm posting here because it's a Project Euler problem, & I have working code that presumably has bugs in it.

The question [Determing longest repeating cycle in a decimal expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080691/determing-longest-repeating-cycle-in-a-decimal-expansion)  solves the problem using logarithms, but I'm interested in solving with simple brute force. More accurately, I'm interested in understanding why my algorithm and code is not returning the correct solution.

The algorithm is simple:

- replicate a 'long division',
- at each step record the divisor and the remainder
- when a divisor / remainder tuple is repeated, infer that the decimal representation will repeat.

Here are private fields, as requested

```
private int numerator; 
private int recurrence; 
private int result; 
private int resultRecurrence; 
private List<dynamic> digits;
```

and here is the code:

```
private void Go()
{
    foreach (var i in primes)
    {
        digits = new List<dynamic>();
        numerator = 1;
        recurrence = 0;

        while (numerator != 0)
        {
            numerator *= 10;

            // quotient
            var q = numerator / i;

            // remainder
            var r = numerator % i;
            digits.Add(new { Divisor = q, Remainder = r });

            // if we've found a repetition then break out
            var m = digits.Where(p => p.Divisor == q && p.Remainder == r).ToList();
            if (m.Count > 1)
            {
                recurrence = digits.LastIndexOf(m[0]) - digits.IndexOf(m[0]);
                break;
            }
            numerator = r;
        }

        if (recurrence > resultRecurrence)
        {
            resultRecurrence = recurrence;
            result = i;
        }
}}
```

When testing integers < 10 and < 20 I get the correct result; and I correctly identify the value of `i` as well. However the decimal represetation that I get is incorrect - I calculate `i-1` whereas the correct result is far less (something like `i-250`).

So presumably I either have a programming bug - which I can't find - or a logic bug.

I'm confused because it feels like a [multiplicative group over p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) to me, in which there would be p-1 elements.  I'm sure I'm missing something, can anyone provide suggestions?

**edit**

I'm not going to include my prime number code - it's not relevant, as I explain above I correctly identify the value of `i` (from memory it is 983) but I'm having problems getting the correct value for `resultRecurrence`.

Comment: Can you tell us which language you wrote the code in? I thought it was javascript and then realised it couldn't be.

Comment: @Phil - added c# tag - it's not a c# specific question but I suppose the tag belongs.

Comment: Can you post the whole code, where the variables `primes`, `digits`, `numerator`, `recurrence`, `resultRecurrence` and `result` are declared? If these are parameters to a method, show us the method signature as well as how you invoke it.

Comment: Is there any reason that you’re using a weakly typed `List`?

Comment: @Konrad not particularly, but I didn't see any reason to use a strongly typed list either. This is just an isolated problem solving method so whatever works seemed fine for the task.

Comment: @Kirk *Always* use strong typing, unless you have very compelling reasons not to. Strong typing is there for good reasons! The compiler is helping you detect errors, which it cannot if you shut down the static type checker.

Comment: @Konrad I understand - but by that logic, what is the purpose of the `dynamic` type?

Comment: @Kirk `dynamic` is a handy shortcut for using reflection. This is necessary when interfacing with dynamic languages/libraries such as IronPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused because it feels like a multiplicative group over p to me, in which there would be p-1 elements. I'm sure I'm missing something, can anyone provide suggestions?

Close.

For all primes except 2 and 5 (which divide 10), the sequence of remainders is formed by starting with 1 and transforming by

```
remainder = (10 * remainder) % prime
```

thus the *k*-th remainder is 10<sup>*k*</sup> (mod prime) and the set of remainders forms a subgroup of the group of nonzero remainders modulo prime[1]. The length of the recurring cycle is the order of that subgroup, which is also known as the order of 10 modulo prime.

The order of the group of nonzero remainders modulo prime is `prime-1`, and there's a theorem by Fermat:

> Let `G` be a finite group of order `g` and `H` be a subgroup of `G`. Then the order `h` of `H` divides `g`.

So the length of the cycle is always a divisor of `prime-1`, and sometimes it's `prime-1`, e.g. for 7 or 19.

[1] For composite numbers `n` coprime to 10, that would be the group of remainders modulo `n` that are coprime to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don’t need the divisors, you only need the remainders.

Secondly, I would split the function into multiple independent parts instead of having everything in one big method: The long division / finding of the cycle length is independent of the rest (= finding the longest cycle).

Your `break` on `Where` coupled with `Count` is unintuitive. Why not just use a `while` loop with the condition `(! digits.Contains(r))`? (This would require putting `0` as a remainder into the `digits` list before the loop start.)

This leaves us with a much cleaner code that should be straightforward to debug.

Comment: I originally started by looking at digits rather than remainders; I then decided I need to look at remainders but kept the digits. You're right - there's no need to keep the digit calculation or storage in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
recurrence = digits.LastIndexOf(m[0]) - digits.IndexOf(m[0]);
```

Surely the value of `resultRecurrence` is *always* going to be `i-1` ? Since for a fraction of the form `1/n`, the decimal starts repeating exactly when the division-in-progress (the `i`th digit) gives the same quotient-remainder as the *very first* trial division (`1`, hence `i-1`).

(as a side note, may I introduce you to [`Math.DivRem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.divrem.aspx)).

Comment: I made the same assumption but as you see in my question, that is **not** the correct answer (according to Project Euler, who I'm inclined to believe)

Comment: The assumption is wrong: there are numbers whose cycle doesn’t start right after the decimal point. If you took `i - 1` as the answer, this would assume that the cycle started with the first decimal digit.