# calculate decimal fraction and show digits after decimal in a precise manner

Tags: c++, c, decimal, floating-point-precision

Given a fraction *(103993/33102)*, I need to find 50000 digits after the decimal point for this fraction.

Initially I used `setprecision(k)` in C++, but it gives only 17 digits after decimal point. I also tried

```
sprintf (str, "%.500000f", num)
```

but the result is the same.

I need an algorithm that can solve this and which does not round off the digits after  the decimal point i.e., it should be precise.

Comment: You are seriously asking us how to do long division?! Please tell me you aren't a programmer who doesn't know how to do long division. This is taught in 4th and 5th grade! Try this [math is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division3.html) page. I know people argue over how much higher math is needed to be a programmer, but needing to know how to do basic arithmetic should be uncontroversial!

Comment: ... I'm at a loss for words.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: long division to 50000 digits is hard, I doubt most coders could do it without a library.  (obvious answer is use a library)

Comment: @Mooing Duck It's actually not - once you realize that all you need to do is carry over the remainder from the division of the digit higher, and store/print out the result for each digit you calculate. It's not like you're making a whole big decimal library :)

Comment: @Patashu: right, I got confused with bignum/bignum, forgot that bignum/int is easy.  He should be able to do long division.

Comment: i dont know about other countries, but if you have studied in INDIA, you must know long precision division.... and still if you want a prepared library....you can use this...http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 4):

The best way to work out how to solve a problem like this is to take a ridiculously easy problem and work out the algorithm on that. That way, you won't get confused or lose your place, and the algorithm is the same regardless of the problem. So let's take `4/3`.

1. 4 goes into 3 once. We have 1 left over. We output the `1.` for the one time it went in. We keep the 1 left over.
2. We multiply the 1 left over by 10 to get 10. 3 (our denominator) goes into 10 three times. With 1 left over.
3. We output the `3` because it went in three times. We still have 1 left over.
4. We go to step 2 and repeat as many times as we need to.

This same algorithm works just this simply regardless of the numerator and denominator, so long as they are positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Float or double will not do it because they are not precise enough. Others have suggested to use a bignum library. This can be done, but there is another way that works directly with integers.

A technique called modular exponentiation can be used to solve this problem. This lets you calculate all digits without ever running into precision problems.

Fortunately an answer how to do this has already been written:

[Getting a specific digit from a ratio expansion in any base (nth digit of x/y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804934/getting-a-specific-digit-from-a-ratio-expansion-in-any-base-nth-digit-of-x-y)