# Infinite lazy lists of digits

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, number-theory

So I'm trying to do some number theory work, and I was using Mathematica but thought that Haskell would be more suited to dealing with infinite lists (as AFAIK Mathematica doesn't have lazy evaluation).  What I want to do is have Haskell store all the digits of 1/x in an infinite lazy list.  So far my searching has not turned up a way to split a ratio into its digits that returns a list of digits rather than an actual floating point number.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804934/getting-a-specific-digit-from-a-ratio-expansion-in-any-base-nth-digit-of-x-y

Comment: @SamYonnou is pointing in the right direction. Before you get into the bit-fiddly stuff, however, remember that Haskell has *very good* built-in bignum support: the Integer type. It may still be necessary to fiddle bits, but it may not. Remember to use quotrem instead of divmod whenever possible.

Comment: You may find this StackExchange post interesting: “Functional style using lazy lists?”: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists The question inspired Mathematica package which is referenced in one of the answers.

Comment: @SamYonnou, that page had the answer I needed.  Thanks.
Final code was:
`nDigRat :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`
`nDigRat num denom n = floor (fromIntegral (10*(10^(n-1)*num \`rem\` denom)) / fromIntegral denom) \`rem\` 10`
`decExpansionRecipRat :: Int -> [Int]` 
decExpansionRecipRat n = map (nDigRat 1 n) [1..]`

Comment: kocho - you should post that as an answer so it's easier to read

Comment: It doesn't address your question directly, but [Conal Elliott's blog entry on adding infinite digit lists](http://conal.net/blog/posts/adding-numbers) might be worth a read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also implement this as a simple stream producer:

```
divDigits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
divDigits x y = x `div` y : divDigits (10 * (x `mod` y)) y
```

There are actually libraries for this kind of "infinite"-precision number representation using lazy lists, see [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/Mathematics#Dynamic_precision_by_lazy_evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to Sam Yonnou, the link he provided had the right formula 
The formula used: 
the nth digit of x/y is the 1st digit of (10^(n-1)*x mod y)/y = floor(10 * (10^(n-1)*x mod y) / y) mod 10 
 
The ending code looked like this:

```
nDigRat :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
nDigRat num denom n = floor (fromIntegral (10*(10^(n-1)*num `rem` denom)) / 
                             fromIntegral denom) 
                      `rem` 10

decExpansionRecipRat :: Int -> [Int]
decExpansionRecipRat n = map (nDigRat 1 n) [1..]
```